# Why can't i get the correct information from an array on my server

Tags: reactjs, server

UPDATED QUESTION

I am building a react web app and have just started to host some of the data on an api. When I try to get to the data it works one way but not another. See below.

WORKING

```
//server side
app.use('/data', (req, res) => {
   res.send({
      name: ["A", "B", "C"]
});

//React side
const url = "http://localhost:8080/data";
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data.name)
//output
"A", "B", "C"
```

However this does not work

```
//server side
app.use('/data', (req, res) => {
   res.send({
      information: [{
      name: "A"
      },
      {
      name: "B"
      },
      {
      name: "C"}]
});

//React side
   const url = "http://localhost:8080/data";
   const response = await fetch(url);
   const data = await response.json();
   console.log(data.information.name)
   //output
   undefined
   //If i do this i get an array back
   console.log(data.information)
   //output
   (3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

I can click into that and see that my information is there but cant seem to target it?

Comment: Since `information` is an array, you need to specify which item you want to access. Try this `console.log(data.information[0].name)`

Comment: Sorry yes i should of mentioned. I know that works but i want to get the entire array and store it as a state for use later.

Comment: Storing information in state is unrelated to your question. With your updated code you receive an array of objects, where each object has `name` property. If you want to get all the names from your new structure, you can do the following `const names = data.information.map((entry) => entry.name);`.

Comment: Sorry assumed it was irrelevant due to the method i was getting the data originally. But now seeing the method it makes sense not sure how I didnt think of it xD. Thanks :)